# Mac App Store Download Failure - Clear Cache?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I bought a program on the Mac App Store (Desk) on one of my computers.

I am running Yosemite on a different computer and I tried to install the program from the Mac App Store - while I was on a public WiFi connection that blocks the Mac App Store. The download failed - but any attempt since then on that computer fails to download that one app.

Whenever I attempt to "Install" the program in the Mac App Store it eventually times out and I receive the following error:

"We could not complete your purchase. The request timed out."
I can download and install other apps just fine.

When I attempt to download I see the following in the console:

```
2/13/15 9:53:20.491 AM storeaccountd[351]: ADI: {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=604800";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Wed, 28 Jan 2015 15:26:24 GMT";
    Location = "http://10.66.66.66/denied.html";
    Server = "squid/2.6.STABLE21";
    Via = "1.1 8802 (squid/3.3.5)";
    "X-Cache" = "MISS from 8802";
}
```

I believe what has happened is that the App Store Web View has cached the redirect to the "denied" page from the public WiFi, but I don't know how to fix this.

1. I have rebooted
2. I have restarted App Store
3. I have Cleared Cache in Safari
4. I tried delete this files:

   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80000gp/C/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent+com.apple.appstore
   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80001z2/C/com.apple.appstore
   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80001z2/C/com.apple.appstore/com.apple.appstore
   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80001z2/C/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent+com.apple.appstore
   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80001z2/T/com.apple.appstore
   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80001z2/T/com.apple.appstore.PluginXPCService
   - /private/var/folders/tv/mw9ndb1s7qn76_xtbg8zy3v80001z2/T/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent+com.apple.appstore

Comment: I would strongly discourage anyone deleting files from /private. if you feel that's needed, I recommend a safe boot instead and possibly reinstalling the same version of your macOS - it's faster in the end for you to know you have a good install than mucking about in machine generated and indexed temporary files - throw out all /private if you suspect it's bad and not cleaning up after itself properly.

Answer (score 30):

Got this sorted out.

1. Quit App Store.
2. Use **Terminal** or Activity Monitor to quit/ force quit  the following processes and to delete the following folders:

   ```
    killall storeaccountd
    killall storeassetd
    killall storedownloadd
    killall storeinappd
    killall appstoreagent
    rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/storeaccountd
    rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/storeassetd
    rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/storedownloadd
    rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/storeinappd
   ```
3. Restart App Store and hold the option key down to cancel any stuck downloads.
4. Then try a download again

Comment: and the root cause was ??

Comment: Root cause - open wifi blocked the AppStore and the AppStore cached the denied redirect. Clearing all the caches fixed it

Comment: Beautiful answer. I don't like mucking in /var/folders and this is much cleaner. Cheers and thanks for nailing this down. [Cache invalidation is hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188587/cache-invalidation-is-there-a-general-solution).

Comment: killall storeaccountd; killall storeassetd; killall storedownloadd; killall storeinappd; rm -r ~/Library/Caches/storeaccountd; rm -r ~/Library/Caches/storeassetd; rm -r ~/Library/Caches/storedownloadd; rm -r ~/Library/Caches/storeinappd

Comment: This didn't work for me, however, I held down the option key and clicked the cancel that appeared on the button and was able to restart that way.

Comment: @bmike Is there a similar procedure for stuck Books downloads?

Comment: I haven’t had to troubleshoot that. Perhaps a new thread picking what version of OS on a specific platform might be in order @orome