# MacOS Mojave disappear after successful download

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, mojave

I just download the Mojave from mac app store and after success download the Installation file disappear from Application folder and Launchpad!
I do twice download it and same happened.  its not like a small file to download it, its 6 GB and I can't understand why this happens.

How can I figure out what's deleting this or get a good download?

Comment: The installer launches automatically immediately after downloading. Did you notice it?

Comment: it doesn't launched, like it's never downloaded

Comment: the problem still exist and now it download a 22 MB file as installer and after taht nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download performs a check to be sure the package is complete and not tampered with. I wonder if that's deleting what it thinks is a bad download and some bug or system modification is stopping you from getting the typical user alert telling you that the download is being deleted without the option to save it.

First steps, check the console app and look at `/var/log/install.log`

If there's no helpful item - you could always get with Apple support to troubleshoot. I often look at other logs like system.log but there can be thousands of entries so if you are looking at all the machine logs for the first time, it might be painful to search for or see the item that's relevant.

If you're game, these are the sorts of files and locations you'll move to if your App Store itself is broken and it's not a server side issue with the account or just a bad network where you can't get a reliable download of that large a size. I've had overseas networks where they mess with SSL certificates or just corrupt the data horribly that cause this.

- [Mac App Store Download Failure - Clear Cache?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171827/mac-app-store-download-failure-clear-cache)

Comment: it seems to be ssl validation problem or man in middle hijack, I use a VPN service and it download 100% ok.

Comment: Nice recovery @OceanOne - it's still a miss for Apple - they should be clear to you and other end users when the network is likely being hostile.