# Big Sur update keeps failing when downloading

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade, big-sur

I am trying to update my Macbook Air 13'' 2017. When I first tried it, it failed. When I tried it again, the progress bar would quickly progress to 713 MB, wait there for a while. Then it continues to download, goes till 5.5 GB, and then it fails again. This is the message I get.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried the following:

- Deleted the folders in `/Library/Updates/`
- Deleted the files in `/private/var/folders/zz/<hash>/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate`

Each time, it still fails

Comment: I was going to answer this but I’ll edit my answer on the dipuplicate question. In your case, since you messed with caches, do a safe boot before proceeding. The download errors are all waiting for Apple CDN and not that your specific Mac has anything wrong.

Comment: @bmike I tried `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer`. It again gets stuck at 5% (713 MB) and fails at 45% (~5GB).

Comment: Hit us up in [chat] - you might want to set up a caching service so that you can cache the files locally - I'm seeing 35% failure rate still - the servers are overloaded. Was your safe boot good and are you running the update from safe boot or normal boot after the safe one? I have never had to resort to a deep clean, but once you start messing with cached files, you might need to do this or erase... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/171832/5472