# Why can't I download anything from Apple?

Tags: mac-appstore, books

Recently anything I try to download from Apple, ether in App Store or Books, gets stuck forever and refuses to unstick.

Here's what it looks like in App Store:

[image]

Books also shows an endless stuck progress bar (or just an undownloaded book). I've rebooted, force quite both apps, logged out and back into my accounts, removed all store related temp files (e.g. `$TMPDIR../C/com.apple.appstore/`) and done `killall storedownloadd` and `killall appstoreagent`. I've also flushed my DNS cache and rebooted my router. I get 200-500 Mbps download speeds (according to Speedtest, etc.), and I have no issues downloading to my phone or Apple TV using the same Apple ID. I have no issue downloading other content of any kind.

Moreover, if I check for available downloads, I get:

[image]

And I see zero network activity from Books or the App Store or any related process.

This is clearly a problem on Apple's end, and I have contacted support multiple times; but I can't figure out *what the magic question is*, so I keep getting entirely useless advice. Once, about a month ago, I had the same thing happen with a book, and support did something so that the next time I logged into Books a previously unseen option to "cancel download" appeared in the context menu for the stuck book. Choosing that did indeed stop the download, which could then be restarted with success.

How do I get Apple downloads to my Mac to start working again?

Comment: OS and app versions: Always the latest of everything.

Comment: Do you have a firewall or Little Snitch etc? You have to let any Apple service use any connection & also for good measure, open up all of 17.x.x.x

Comment: 'the latest' would be better in actual numbers, because if someone find this question next year, they won't know what the current 'latest' was.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have LS but it is off while I try to fix this. In any case there are no relevant denied connections listed in LS.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is there something I could do to clear any pending downloads and clear all relevant caches to force downlad. E.g. something [like this procedure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/171832/4395), except for Books?